# An idiom involving walking on a branch

Tags: idioms, idiom-requests

I am *reasonably certain* that once, glancing over a long list of English idioms, I saw an idiom that I now remember as "walk on a branch" and cannot find anywhere, so my memory must be wrong.

The listed meaning was "to give it a long shot", "to make a not-necessarily-educated guess", the implication being that it is similar to stepping on a tree's branch that may crack under you foot.

I cannot look this idiom up anywhere, to the point where I am starting to doubt it even existed.

It was *not*:

- [walk on eggshells](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/182137/524)
- [walk on thin ice](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/322539/524)
- walk the plank

Does it exist, and if so, what is it?

Comment: I might be going out on a limb here, but would it be ["going out on a limb"](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/go+out+on+a+limb)?

Comment: @Hellion Hmm... I certainly did consider it when writing up the question, but ended up not including it because its meaning - "to express an unpopular opinion", "to go against the group" - seemed less close than that of the others. Now looking at some [other sources](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/go_out_on_a_limb), it seems like it may be the one, and the meanings I looked up for it earlier are not even listed there.

Comment: Going out on a limb means to take a risky chance, not specifically negative.

Comment: @GSerg A common usage of *go out on a limb* is to preface expressing a delicate opinion or suggestion, but this is just a frequent use, not the core meaning, which is indeed, to take a risk.

Comment: @Hellion - This is reminding me of a [Kids in the hall sketch](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=nbPcAEQAlF4)

Comment: @Hellion It has to be the one. My attempts to find it were thwarted by the unfortunate definition I stumbled upon first. Please make it an answer.

Comment: Yeah, it just can't not be the one! :D Here's a good link (including origin): https://knowyourphrase.com/go-out-on-a-limb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for ***[go out on a limb](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/go+out+on+a+limb)***.

As [freedictionary.com](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/go+out+on+a+limb) puts it:

> To do or say something that lacks evidence or support.

Or, as [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/go_out_on_a_limb) says:

> - *(idiomatic)* To take a risk.
> - *(idiomatic)* To hazard a guess

[KnowYourPhrase.com](https://knowyourphrase.com/go-out-on-a-limb) agrees almost completely with Wiktionary:

> 1. Putting yourself in a risky or precarious situation in order to help someone.
> 2. Taking a wild guess at something or expressing an opinion that might not be shared by others.